# Print date into html date picker

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am having problems printing a date stored in my db on a date input field.
Before I had it as `type="text"` and the date would show whenever I loaded the page. However, I changed the type to `type="date"` so that the users do not have to type the date every time they want to change it. However, the text field is not being preloaded with the date, now it only shows `"mm/dd/yyyy"`

I would like to be able to see the date that is saved in the db when I load the page, and then if I want to make changes, just use the date picker.

Here is the code. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
<input ng-model="vm.adminSettings.projectDeadlineStartDate"
       class="form-control" type="date"
       style="margin-left: 1px; margin-right: 5px;"
       title="Start Deadline" required />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)

Comment: Use angular directives for that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it like this

```js
document.getElementById("myDate").defaultValue = "2014-02-09";
```

```html
<input id="myDate" type="date" name="" value="2019">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try modifying/formatting your projectDeadlineStartDate attribute to a javascript date object. check this example:

```
 angular.module('dateInputExample', [])
 .controller('DateController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   var dateFromDb = "2019-03-08" //your date value from db
   $scope.vm.projectDeadline = new Date(dateFromDb);
   };
 }])
```